# How can I rotate back?

Tags: wcf

I am developing a wcf service for Windows 8 APP. But I'm choked up at one point. 
The following method, it is coming data in the database using entity. But this the data returns back to a class type. My question , if result is null what can I sent person who will this method

```
 public AnketorDTO AnketorBul(string tc, string pass)
    {
        _entity = new AnketDBEntities();
        var result = (from i in _entity.Anketors
                          where i.TC == tc
                          where i.Sifre == pass
                          select i).ToList();
        if (!result.Any())
     -->>>   return new AnketorDTO();

        Anketor anketor = result.First();
        return Converter.ConvertAnketorToAnketorDTO(anketor);
    }
```

with this methot I SENT it by creating a new class type but part  which use  this methot does not work because the values become null. how can we  prevent it.

Client :

```
AnketorDTO anketor = await client.AnketorBulAsync(txtKullanici.Text, txtSifre.Password);
            **if (anketor != null)
                lblError.Text = anketor.Adi;**
            else
                lblError.Text = "Hata";
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this method to see, if it works?

```
_entity = new AnketDBEntities();
var result = _entity.Anketors.FirstOrDefault(yourexpressions);
```

Comment: I tired this. Unfortunately didn't work. What can we do at client side for taking null class types to client side from WCF?